# Does native Delphi HTTPClient support SNI?

Tags: http, delphi, sni

We have to include SNI (Server_Name_Indication) in our rest requests because the server will hosts several virtual domains in the near future. We are using a standard THTTPClient component created at runtime.
As soon as we add a new domain with new certificate we receive an exception
"Server certificate invalid or does not exist"
(translated from the german error text)

Is there a special header value to archive SNI this like for the basic authentication?

Below is a simplified version of our code (no logging, no proxy, fake URL). I apologize that I can not provide the real URL we are using.

We would expect that we must augment the GetRequest method, but did not find any example or hint.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, WinApi.WinHTTP, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  System.Net.HTTPClient;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    function PostRequest(const cRequest, cBody: string): string;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

type
  TMyRestClient = class(TObject)
  private
    fHTTPClient: THTTPClient;
    fSysUrl: string;
    fUserID: string;
    fPassWD: string;
    //...
    function GetRequest(const cMethod, cUrl: string): IHTTPRequest;
  public
    constructor Create(const cUrl: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Post(const cRequest, cBody: string): string;

    //...
    property SystemUrl: string read fSysUrl write fSysUrl;
    property Username: string read fUserID write fUserID;
    property Password: string read fPassWD write fPassWD ;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.NetEncoding;

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TMyRestClient.Create(const cUrl: string);
begin
  fHTTPClient := THTTPClient.Create;
  SystemUrl := cUrl;
end;

destructor TMyRestClient.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(fHTTPClient);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function TMyRestClient.GetRequest(const cMethod, cUrl: string): IHTTPRequest;
begin
  Result := fHTTPClient.GetRequest(cMethod, cUrl);
  Result.AddHeader('content-type', 'appplication/json');
  if (Password <> '') then
    Result.AddHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(Username + ':' + Password));
end;

function TMyRestClient.Post(const cRequest, cBody: string): string;
var
  iRequest: IHTTPRequest;
  iResponse: IHTTPResponse;
  aBody: TStringStream;
begin
  iRequest := GetRequest('POST', Format('%s/%s', [SystemUrl, cRequest]));
  aBody := TStringStream.Create(UTF8String(cBody));
  try
    iRequest.SourceStream := aBody;
    iResponse := fHTTPClient.Execute(iRequest);
  finally
    aBody.DisposeOf;
  end;
  if (iResponse.StatusCode <> HTTP_STATUS_OK) then
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('Post: %s failed (Code %d) %', [cRequest, iResponse.StatusCode, iResponse.StatusText]);
  Result := iResponse.ContentAsString;
end;

function TForm1.PostRequest(const cRequest, cBody: string): string;
var
  xClient: TMyRestClient;
begin
  xClient := TMyRestClient.Create('www.myserver.com/demo');
  try
    // Basic authentification (not used)
    xClient.Username := '';
    xClient.Password := '';
    Result := xClient.Post(cRequest, cBody);
  finally
    xClient.DisposeOf
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.Text := PostRequest('retrieve/paramvalue', '{''PARAM'':''VERSION''}' );
end;
```

Comment: Typically this is handled as an extension to the TLS stack that your http client is using after you set the hostname.  I don't use the System.Net.HttpClient unit, but I believe it relies on the platform specific http implementation.  OpenSSL has a method called SSL_set_tlsext_host_name() so if you are using an OpenSSL based http client that would be a cross-platform approach.  A quick scan of the Delphi source shows that the Indy stack has this feature if the OPENSSL_NO_TLSEXT define is not defined.  Remy could probably comment more on this topic.

Comment: At the HTTP layer, the `Host` request header specifies the (virtual) host being accessed. When using HTTPS, the TLS stack that carries the HTTP request has to include the TLS SNI extension in the handshake to specify the same host name. You can't set that at the HTTP layer alone, you need access to the TLS layer, too.  I have no idea if/how Embarcadero handles this internally.

Comment: Okay I got the point. Also checked out that SecureBlackBox offers SNI support, but we switched to the native component recently because we wanted to avoid the maintenance of OpenSSL libraries in our distribution.